# How do I introduce encapsulation in the following Java program?

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation

I have created the following Java program. Its basic functionality is to perform addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and modular division on two numbers.

I have implemented the concept of object-oriented programming, but it is missing encapsulation.

How do I introduce encapsulation in it?

My code is:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


/**
 *
 * @author piyali
 */

public class Calculator {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO code application logic here
        int x, y;
        x = 13;
        y = 5;

        calculation add = new calculation();
        calculation sub = new calculation();
        calculation mul = new calculation();
        calculation div = new calculation();
        calculation mod = new calculation();

        int addResult = add.addition(x, y);
        int subResult = sub.subtraction(x, y);
        int mulResult = mul.multiplication(x, y);
        int divResult = mul.division(x, y);
        int modResult = mod.modularDivision(x, y);

        System.out.println("The addition of the numbers is " +addResult);
        System.out.println("The subtraction of the two numbers is " +subResult);
        System.out.println("The multiplication of the two numbers is " + mulResult);
        System.out.println("The division of the two numbers is " +divResult);
        System.out.println("The modular division of the two numbers is " + modResult);
    }
}

class calculation {

    int addition(int x, int y){
        int z;
        z = x + y;
        return(z);
    }

    int subtraction(int x, int y){
        int z;
        z = x - y;
        return(z);
    }

    int multiplication(int x, int y){
        int z;
        z = x * y;
        return(z);
    }

    int division(int x, int y){
        int z;
        z = x / y;
        return(z);
    }

    int modularDivision(int x, int y){
        int z;
        z = x % y;
        return(z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that encapsulation involves the protection of data members aka fields. If you don't have fields then you're not exposing something which needs to be encapsulated.

Comment: Here I can easily do something like say Calculation b = new Calculation, b.z = 12, I guess If int z was declared outside function say addition(), encapsulation would come in handy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want true OOP and encapsulation, then create interface `Calculation` which has a method `int calculate()`.

```
public interface Calculation {

     int calculate();
}
```

Now create classes which implements this interface such as `Addition` or `Subtraction` etc.

```
public class Addition implements Calculation {

     private final int x;
     private final int y;

     public Addition(int x, int y) {
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
     }

     @Override
     public int calculate(){
         return x + y;
     }
 }
```

Main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x, y;
    x = 13;
    y = 5;

    Calculation add = new Addition(x, y);
    System.out.println(add.calculate());
}
```

Advantages of such design is that if you will want to add any extra mathematical operations such as root, percentage or even derivation, you will not need to modify any implementation of class. Just write extra class which implements `Calculation`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much to encapsulate here. This looks like it wants to be a basic math library, and since it has no data members, or helper functions, you can't do a whole lot here to encapsulate.

Since creating an instance of this class is a bit silly (see the Java Math library for example), make the methods static, and make the constructor private.

I guess not a form of encapsulation, but some design tips: You should make variables you aren't modifying final. You should also remove all unnecessary variables if you aren't using them. They aren't doing anything for readability, and they're just using extra blocks of memory (unless the JVM optimizes them out).

Improved code:

```java
class calculation {
    private calculation() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Don't instantiate a math library!");
    }

    public static int addition(final int x, final int y){
        return x + y;
     }

    public static int subtraction(final int x, final int y){
        return x - y;
    }

    public static int multiplication(final int x, final int y){
        return x * y;
    }

    public static int division(final int x, final int y){
        return x / y;
    }

    public static int modularDivision(final int x, final int y){
        return x % y;
    }
}
```

By doing this, now you can call your calculation library with something like this:

```
int additionResult = calculation.addition(5, 5);
System.out.println(additionResult);
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the concept of getter and setter.

```
class Calculator{
private int x, y, z;

void setValue(int a, int b){
    x=a;
    y=b;
}

int getValue(){
    return z;
}

void addition(){
    z=x+y;
}

void subtraction(){
    z=x-y;
}

void multiplication(){
    z=x*y;
}

void division(){
    z=x/y;
}

void modDivision(){
    z=x%y;
}
}


public class CalculatorTestDrive {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int num1, num2, result;

    num1=13;
    num2=5;

    Calculator add = new Calculator();
    Calculator sub = new Calculator();
    Calculator mul = new Calculator();
    Calculator div = new Calculator();
    Calculator mod = new Calculator();

    add.setValue(num1, num2);
    add.addition();
    result = add.getValue();
    System.out.println("The addition of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is " +result);

    sub.setValue(num1, num2);
    sub.subtraction();
    result = sub.getValue();
    System.out.println("The subtraction of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is " +result);

    mul.setValue(num1, num2);
    mul.multiplication();
    result = mul.getValue();
    System.out.println("The multiplication of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is " +result);

    div.setValue(num1, num2);
    div.division();
    result = div.getValue();
    System.out.println("The division of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is " +result);

    mod.setValue(num1, num2);
    mod.modDivision();
    result = mod.getValue();
    System.out.println("The modular division of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is " +result);
}

}
```

Comment: This is a worse design than the existing code. It is more verbose, and makes the code non-reentrant, meaning there are now threading issues which weren't there before.

Comment: Then please post an answer yourself with correct design